# Suggest [python-os] when [python] and [operating-system] tags used

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, questions

I frequently see [operating-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operating-system) used in Python questions that use the `os` module. These questions aren't about operating systems, and this presumably came about because [os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os) is a synonym ([1837 questions tagged [python] [os] -[python-os]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+operating-system+-python-os)).

Is there some way the system could suggest that they probably want [python-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-os) instead?

There are other similar pairs, since many popular Python libraries have the same name as general concepts. Today I corrected the tag [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click) to [python-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-click).

Comment: Maybe adding something like *"FOR QUESTIONS ABOUT PYTHON'S os LIBRARY, USE [python-os]"* to the start of [operating-system's tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/operating-system/info) will help?

Comment: haha, you think posters read tag wikis!

Comment: Do we even need a python-os tag? ~500 (surviving)  questions since 2012 suggests it isn't pulling its weight.

Comment: @snakecharmerb That's a good question, maybe it's only needed so we have an alternative to `os` in these cases.

Comment: Based on a very unscientific rapid sampling of the tag, it looks to me like it largely relates to doing things with files and directories. Not sure these activities are so special they need their own tag.  And there is a lot of cross-over with the  `shutil`, `io` and `pathlib` modules in the stdlib, I suspect (unscientifically).

Comment: That's hardly surprising. `os.path.XXX` and `os.walk` probably account for the vast majority of uses.

Comment: What I really want is to discourage people from spamming the `operating-system` tag. As long as this other tag exists, it's an appropriate substitute. If it didn't exist, I'd want to tell people "You probably don't want this tag".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we don't have a way to do this at the moment. Our tag warnings use the same mechanism our blocklists do -- associate *one* specific tag with some provided warning or error text. Upgrading this system to perform logic on combinations of tags would be a nontrivial amount of work.

I see the use case here, and I think it's a good one, but I'd be skeptical to say that this request by itself justifies an expansion of the tag blocklist feature. That said, if there's a broader argument for this feature to exist, involving multiple requests or use cases for tag combination warnings / blocks, I'd say that would make for a solid feature request of its own merit. If you think there's a strong enough line of reasoning, I'd encourage you to make such a post, and cite this as one practical use case in that feature request.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this. It's annoying because there are other similar common mistakes; just a few minutes ago I corrected `click` to `python-click`.